# False positives with automatic duplicate detection and question differentiation

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, quality-filter

I recently asked and answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833537/android-mediaplayer-videoview-error-1-2147483648) and the site has auto-tagged it as a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648).

The error mentioned in both questions is the same, (1, -2147483648), but the solutions are very different.  The error itself is "MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN", which would indicate that there are perhaps many different things wrong and hence many different ways to fix it.

I wouldn't have found the answer to this question without searching that exact error code, and I'm not sure that the question's SEO would be improved by removing it from the title.  How can I improve my question and answer such that it doesn't get auto-detected as a duplicate?

I struggled with that solution for a long time this morning and wouldn't wish that process upon anyone else.

Comment: I can't see that your question is marked as duplicate?

Comment: @AndersUP What the OP means here is that the system wouldn't let them post their question, because its title is nearly identical to an older question. spitzanator, "duplicate" on SO usually refers to a question being closed as a duplicate of another by real people (5 users with more than 3K rep), perhaps you could slightly rephrase your question here to better explain what the actual issue was.

Comment: I cleaned up the question a bit per @Yannis's suggestion.  Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Yannis Thanks for clearing that up - that's a feature I didn't know existed...